# Change script that is run on command line to run on a django request

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-views

I have a script that i run from command to populate a django model from csv..
the command i use is:

```
python artifact_db_loader.py -tzusb "d:\Test_Data\david nides\david-nides-usb.csv" -e 44
```

How can i change this to run on a django view?
Anyone with an insight please?
Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

A Django view by definition is a callable that accepts a request object as first argument. If you would like to reused that 1-1, you would need to create a request object manually first.

However, I would strongly recommend not to do so. Refactor the common code into a utility module/function and call this from the view or from the command line script.

Answer (score 0):

To call a management command programatically:

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('your_command')
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) for details.

Comment: Thanks Dirk,In this case "my command is the entire command i run from command line above?"

Comment: No, the first argument of call_command is just the name of your management command. Arguments of your command are added like this: `management.call_command('artifact_db_loader', 'arg', kwarg='abc')`

Comment: In my case python artifact_db_loader.py -tzusb "d:\Test_Data\david nides\david-nides-usb.csv" -e 44 I have 2 arguments, --tzusb(file_path),and -e(44) so i should pass it like  right?

Comment: Dirk,I get an error "unknown command artifact_db_loader" despite adding a module containing it on my project..or is there another way of adding it so that it be recognized as a command?